# Union of two sorted arrays in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I am getting SEGMENTATION FAULT, as error can someone please help me find my mistake,
I realise this isn't the most optimal code, any suggestion would be helpful, thanks

#### QUESTION:

Given two arrays `a[]` and `b[]` of size `n` and `m` respectively. The task is to find union between these two arrays.

Union of the two arrays can be defined as the set containing distinct elements from both the arrays. If there are repetitions, then only one occurrence of element should be printed in the union.

##### Example 1:

Input:

```
5 3
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3
```

Output:

```
5
```

##### Explanation:

1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are the
elements which comes in the union set
of both arrays. So count is 5.

##### Example 2:

Input:

```
6 2 
85 25 1 32 54 6
85 2
```

Output:

```
7
```

Explanation:
85, 25, 1, 32, 54, 6, and
2 are the elements which comes in the
union set of both arrays. So count is 7.
Your Task:
Complete doUnion funciton that takes a, n, b, m as parameters and returns the count of union elements of the two arrays. The printing is done by the driver code.

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ n, m ≤ 105
0 ≤ a[i], b[i] < 105
```

Expected Time Complexity : O((n+m)log(n+m))
Expected Auxilliary Space : O(n+m)

MY ANSWER:

```
//Function to return the count of number of elements in union of two arrays.
    int doUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m)  {
        //code here
        int mac;
            if(a[n-1]>=a[n-2] && a[n-2]>=a[n-3]){
                mac=a[n-1];
            }else{
                mac=a[0];
            }
            int mab;
            if(b[m-1]>=b[m-2] && b[m-2]>=b[m-3]){
                mab=b[m-1];
            }else{
                mab=b[0];
            }
            // cout<<mac<<" "<<mab<<endl;
        
        int ma = max(mac,mab);
        int ptr[ma+1]={0};
        
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        {
            ptr[a[i]]++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            ptr[b[i]]++;
        }
        int u=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<=ma;i++){
            if(ptr[i]>0)
            {
                // cout<<i<<endl;
                u++;
            }
        }
        return u;
        
    }
```

Comment: C++ already provides this feature, q.v. [set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

Comment: So let's see: `{100}, 1, {101}, 1` segfaults on a[-2] access (why is it even trying that?), if it didn't, it would try to allocate `ptr` of size 102 (that's not the expected auxiliary size either). (insert obligatory note about Variable Length Arrays not being valid C++) Are you sure you don't want to think about what you're doing for a bit?

Comment: The word `sorted` wandered into the title, but considering the question body, it's feeling a bit lonely up there. Is the input actually sorted? That does make a difference for the solution. Can we have a [mre] with some data included?

Comment: Actually if it was pre-sorted, you could do this in O(n+m) time with O(1) aux space. So I assume the title is mistaken. "Expected Time Complexity : O((n+m)log(n+m)) Expected Auxilliary Space : O(n+m)" suggests "copy everything into one pile, sort, count unique numbers" as the expected solution.

Comment: This would be sooo much easier with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, using vectors:

**Edited:**  Changed the code to return the quantity of unique values.

```
int doUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m)
{
     std::vector<int> the_union;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
     {
         the_union.push_back(a[i]);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
     {
         the_union.push_back(b[i]);
     }
     std::sort(the_union.begin(), the_union.end());
     std::vector::iterator union_end_iter =  
         std::unique(the_union.begin(), the_union.end());

     // The `std::unique` does not remove the duplicate elements.
     the_union.erase(union_end_iter, the_union.end());
     // Return the number of unique elements:
     return the_union.size();
}
```

The algorithm is:

1. Combine all both arrays into one vector.
2. Sort the vector (this makes the next step easer).
3. Remove all duplicate values so that only unique values are in the vector.
4. Return the size of the vector, which is the number of unique values.

Comment: More efficiency may be achieved by using a dynamically allocated array.  But the question is, how much time is saved and is it not negligible.

Comment: @dratenik: Thanks.  Made appropriate edits.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the C++ solution, keeping the C-Style array function prototype.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int doUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m) {
    std::vector<int> result{};
    std::set_intersection(a, a + n, b, b + m, std::back_inserter(result));
    return result.size();
}


int main() {
    int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };    
    int b[] = {     3,    6,      10,11,12    };
    std::cout << doUnion(a, 9, b, 5);
}
```

And if you want to have real low level stuff, then please see the ugly one below:

```
int doUnion(int a[], int n, int b[], int m) {

    int* x = a;
    int* y = b;
    int counter = 0;

    while (x != (a + n) && y != (b + m)) {
        if (*x < *y) ++x;
        else {
            if (!(*y < *x)){ ++x; ++counter;}
            ++y;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure OP's inputs are actually sorted? If not, your solutions won't work. Also what about "Expected Auxilliary Space : O(n+m)" for #2?

Comment: No, I am not sure. Of course input need to be sorted. If not sorted, then let's sort it using std::sort. Regarding auxiliary space. It should be m+n. What did I do wrong? Maybe some childish typo? Please correct me, then I will edit the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're not actually sorted despite the word appearing in the title (see comments). 212 (`int result[212];`) is not quite O(n+m), if we were to relax the limits on m and n, what size would you use? And you only want the count, so you actually could have done the equivalent in O(1) storage. (so why is the requirement for O(n+m)? because the inputs are not actually sorted...)

Comment: Somehow I was trusting the word "sorted" in the title of the question . . .  But I will delete the answer. Nobody will use it anyway